# Prove that a group is finite iff it has finitely many subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have got the following task:
Prove, that these 2 statements are equivalent

- A $G$ group is finite.
- A $G$ group has finite amount of subgroups.

The trivial side is easy: If $G$ has infinite amount of subgroups, then $G$ can't be finite(The number of subgroups is at most $2^k$, where $k$ is the number of the elements in $G$. If $k$ is finite, $2^k$ will be finite too.

However, the other side doesn't seem so easy. I must prove, that if I have a $G$ group with infinite amount of elements, then the number of subgroups must be infinite aswell.

Any ideas, how should I start proving this? Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Let $G$ be an infinite group. Each $g$ in $G$ generates a subgroup $\langle g\rangle=\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$. There are two cases.

- All of the groups $\langle g\rangle$ are finite.
- There is at least one $g\in G$ such that $\langle g\rangle$ is infinite.

The first should be easy. For the second, show that $\langle g\rangle$ is isomorphic to a very familiar group that has infinitely many subgroups.

Comment: For the second, you mean, that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Atvin: That’s right.

Comment: I have some questions about your statement. What exactly do you mean by each $g$ in $G$ generates a subgroup? You mean, that every element of $G$ creates a subgroup with the following attitude?

Comment: @Atvin: I’m assuming that you know that for any $g\in G$, the set $\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. It’s called the subgroup generated by $g$, and $\langle g\rangle$ is a standard notation for it. I just mean for you to look at those subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I see now. :)

Comment: @Atvin: You’re welcome.